# iTunes Search API in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, itunes

Does anyone have experience integrating the iTunes Search API into Rails? I've started off by using the [itunes-search-api](https://github.com/rlivsey/itunes-search-api) gem, but I'm very new to Rails and when the documentation says:

```
ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term => "The Killers", :country => "US", :media => "music")
ITunesSearchAPI.lookup(:id => 284910350)
```

I'm not sure where to begin integrating something like that. I know this is a bit of a broad and beginner question, but I'm just looking for where to begin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has some good documentation for the API at:

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

The itunes-search-api gem appears to forward requests directly.